# Difference between letters used as indices of arbitrary elements in a matrix/vector and letters used as indices of the last element in a matrix/vector

Tags: notation, index-notation

Let's say I want to define a vector $A$.

When I intend to use a particular letter (eg. letter $j$) to index an arbitrary element of vector $A$, can I use the same letter to index the last element of vector $A$ when defining the vector? Like this:

$$A = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ... ,a_{j})$$
where $j$-th element means such and such...

Or do I have to use another letter to index the last element of vector $A$? Like this:

$$A = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ... ,a_{n})$$
where $j$-th element means such and such and where $j \in \text{{$1; 2; ... ;n$}}$

Or could I do this?
$$A = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ... ,a_{N^{(j)}})$$
where $j$-th element means such and such and where $j \in \text{{$1; 2; ... ;N^{(j)}$}}$

If I indeed have to use different letters to index an arbitrary element and the last element of vector $A$, can I use for example $J$ to index the last element when using $j$ to index an arbitrary element of vector $A$? Like this:
$$A = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ... ,a_{J})$$
where $j$-th element means such and such and where $j \in \text{{$1; 2; ... ;J$}}$

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this and will confuse your reader. There is no need for the superscript $(j)$ in
$$
A = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ... ,a_{N^{(j)}}).
$$
Write simply
$$
A = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ... ,a_{N}).
$$
Your vector has $N$ components, independent of any choice you make for how to label an arbitrary component. Then you write
$$
a_j \ \ (j \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}) .
$$
The last element in the vector is simply $a_N$.

Comment: If I use the $N$ multiple times in a document for multiple purposes, do you think that adding the superscript $(j)$ would make the document more intelligible while reading?

Comment: @jmachka. Not at all. It makes it more confusing.

Comment: No. That strange superscript will always be confusing. $N$ is typical for the length of a vector, and can reappear with different lengths at different places in your document. If you suspect the reader will be bothered by that then use different symbols for the different lengths. You might want different letters (not always $a$) for they typical elements of those vectors, too.